# how do I add up the sum of the digits of a number except for digits that repeat themselves in c?

Tags: c

I have an assignment and I need to add up the digits of it and ignore the once that repeat themselves
for example 234111 -> 2 + 3 + 4 + 1 -> 10
I tried doing this:
    #include

```
int main(void)
{
int i = 0;
int num = 0;
int sum = 0;

printf("Please enter a number\n");
scanf("%d", &num);

while(num > 0){

    sum += num%10;
    num /= 10;

}
printf("%d", sum);
return 0;
}
```

what I did just adds up the digits, it doesn't ignore that ones that get repeated
What do i need to add to the code?

Comment: You could try to remember which digits you have already included by making an array of `bool`, where the index of the array is the digit and the value is whether it has been included already or not. and if it has been included already don't add it.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep an array of 'flags' for which digits have been used already:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
//  int i = 0; // You don't actually use this in the code!
    int num = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int used[10] = { 0, }; // Set all "used" flags to zero

    printf("Please enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    while (num > 0)
    {
        int digit = num % 10; // Get the digit
        if (!used[digit]) sum += digit; // Only add if not used already
        used[digit] = 1; // Now we have used it!
        num /= 10;

    }
    printf("%d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: There is no need to set the `used[digit] = 1`, if it was already set :) So better will be: `if (!used[digit]) { sum += digit; used[digit] = 1; }`.

Comment: @VillageTech Sure - matter of style and/or optimizing performance vs clarity.

Comment: @VillageTech One could even do: `if (!(used[digit]++)) sum += digit;` for maximum brevity.

Comment: Nope ;) It makes risk of overflow/overrun in case of very loooong numbers (more than MAX_INT digits) ;) Of course there is no possibility to have such long numbers, but incrementing w/ out control makes things unpredictable and is not a good pattern. and shouldn't be shown as good practice example.

Comment: @VillageTech Good point (but my last comment was light-hearted). I'll leave it for a bit then delete.

Answer (score 0):

Just read each character and record if you've already seen it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
main(void)
{
        int seen[10] = {0};
        int sum = 0;
        int c;
        while( ( c = getchar()) != EOF ) {
                int v = c - '0';
                if( isspace(c)) {
                        continue;
                }
                if( v < 0 || v > 9 ) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
                        return 1;
                }
                if( ! seen[v]++ )
                        sum += v;
        }
        printf("%d\n", sum);
        return 0;
}
```